# How to make download feature (from other website link) in Laravel8?

Tags: php, laravel

Good evening, how to make a download feature (from another website link) in laravel 8?

for example I have a data link "download zip" from the github repository, then I want when I click download (in view) it will download from the github repo link.

actually it can be created in a view like `<a href="$data->link">`, but this method can't add the "download" value in the table.

I want to do this in the controller and when there is a download request it will also add value to the download field (table).

web.php

```
Route::get('source-code/download/{id}', [FrontController::class, 'download'])->name('download');
```

FrontController.php

```
public function download($id)
    {
        $sc = Sourcecode::findOrFail($id);
        $sc->increment('download');
        $sc->update();
        
        if ($sc->file)
            {
                $file_path = public_path('storage/'.$sc->file);
        
                return response()->download($file_path);
            }
        
        else
            {
                $headers = [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
                 ];
      
                return response()->download($sc->link, 'testing.zip', $headers);
            }         
    }
```

view

```
@if($sc->file || $sc->link)
     <a href="{{ route('download', $sc->id) }}" target="_blank"  rel="noopener" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-white">
        Download
     </a>
@endif
```

Currently, I can download from the folder, but from other website links, I still can't. how to make a feature like this? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `reponse()->download` only seems to work on local files. If you want something similar for a remote file you can try the following:

```
public function download($id)
    {
        $sc = Sourcecode::findOrFail($id);
        $sc->increment('download');
        $sc->update();
        
        if ($sc->file)
            {
                $file_path = public_path('storage/'.$sc->file);
        
                return response()->download($file_path);
            }
        
        else
            {
                $data = file_get_contents($sc->link);
                $headers = [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
                    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="testing.zip"',
                    'Content-Length' => strlen($data)
                 ];
        
                return response($data, 200, $headers);
            }         
    }
```

Be aware that this will need to read the entire file in memory.

If the file is large then you can use a [streamed download](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#streamed-downloads)

Comment: wow, it can work well. And then, if the controller using response, how to make a redirect to another page after downloading?

Comment: @HilmiHidayat you can't do that from the server side. You can only send a single response at a time and a redirect is a type of response. Some people manage to do something like this by downloading a file via an iframe with the `src` being the download path and then redirecting a few seconds later (the download would probably not be interrupted) though I've never tested this myself so don't know the limitations